# scala spark count number of change over time in DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

for example i have this type of DataFrame :

```
val DF = Seq((10, "id1",1), 
(20, "id1",6), 
(30, "id1",6), 
(40, "id1",11), 
(50, "id1",1), 
(60, "id1",1), 
(70, "id1",11),
(10, "id2",1), 
(20, "id2",11), 
(30, "id2",1), 
(40, "id2",6), 
(50, "id2",1), 
(60, "id2",11), 
(70, "id2",6)).toDF("Time", "ID","Channel")

+----+---+-------+
|Time| ID|Channel|
+----+---+-------+
|  10|id1|      1|
|  20|id1|      6|
|  30|id1|      6|
|  40|id1|     11|
|  50|id1|      1|
|  60|id1|      1|
|  70|id1|     11|
|  10|id2|      1|
|  20|id2|     11|
|  30|id2|      1|
|  40|id2|      6|
|  50|id2|      1|
|  60|id2|     11|
|  70|id2|      6|
+----+---+-------+
```

I would like for each ID, count the number of changement of the value Channel, over the time. 
To have a result like

```
+---+-----------------------+
| ID|NumberChannelChangement|
+---+-----------------------+
|id1|                      4|
|id2|                      6|
+---+-----------------------+
```

I tried with transform the DataFrame to RDD and iterate over it. 
I do not get the same result from one run to another, when I use the same input.

thank you in advance for the help

Comment: it is 5 and 7 . right?.. how 4 for the id1?

Comment: No no, the changes 4 times through the time for id1 and 6 times pour id2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a combination of analytical functions (`lag`) to detect changes, and `groupBy` to count the changes:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df
.withColumn("lag_Channel",lag($"Channel",1).over(Window.partitionBy($"ID").orderBy($"Time")))
.withColumn("change",coalesce($"Channel"=!=$"lag_channel",lit(false)))
.groupBy($"ID")
.agg(
  sum(when($"change",lit(1))).as("NumberChannelChangement")
)
.show()

+---+-----------------------+
| ID|NumberChannelChangement|
+---+-----------------------+
|id1|                      4|
|id2|                      6|
+---+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you Raphael !

Answer (score 2):

Using spark-sql.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("PierreK ")
spark.sql(
  """  with t1 (select time,id, channel, lag(channel) over(partition by id order by time) chn_lag from pierrek)
       select id, sum( case when chn_lag is null then 0 when channel=chn_lag then 0 else 1 end) as NumberChannelChangement from t1 group by id
  """).show(false)
```

Results:

```
+---+-----------------------+
|id |NumberChannelChangement|
+---+-----------------------+
|id1|4                      |
|id2|6                      |
+---+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution too